# Why does this same expression return True in when entered as a line into the python interpreter and False when run in a script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash, boolean-expression

I have a python script where I've printed the value of two variables. These are dash callback id's. An excerpt is:

```
ctx = dash.callback_context
changed_id = [p['prop_id'] for p in ctx.triggered][0]
order_id = changed_id.split('.')[0]


print(child['props']['id'])
print(order_id)
print(child['props']['id'] ==order_id)
```

The output is:

```
{'type': 'dynamic-order', 'index': 3}
{"index":3,"type":"dynamic-order"}
False
```

But when I copy and past the output of the first two lines and run them directly into the python3 interpreter I get:

```
>>> {'type': 'dynamic-order', 'index': 3}=={"index":3,"type":"dynamic-order"}
True
```

I would expect these should both return the same boolean value. How is it these values are different? Furthermore, why am I getting False in the script and how can I change it so that it evaluates to True?

Comment: What type is `child['props']['id']`? An `OrderedDict` for example, uses the key order in comparing two types, while `dict` does not.

Comment: I think `order_id` is a string. A dict representation would show single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: You're right. Thanks!

Comment: @khelwood: The spacing is also a giveaway; Python `dict` `repr`s always put a space after the `:`s. You can see the type distinction clearly by replacing `print(order_id)` with `print(repr(order_id))` which wouldn't change for a `dict`, but would show the outer string quotes for a `str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `order_id` is actually a string. If it were a dict, Python would use single-quotes there instead of double-quotes, and put spaces after the colons `:` and commas `,`.

It seems to contain JSON, so use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to parse it.

```
import json

order_id = '{"index":3,"type":"dynamic-order"}'
d = {'type': 'dynamic-order', 'index': 3}
print(json.loads(order_id) == d)  # -> True
```

---

In the future, you can use [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) or [`pprint.pprint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) to diagnose issues like this.

```
print(repr(order_id))  # -> '{"index":3,"type":"dynamic-order"}'
print(repr(d))         # -> {'type': 'dynamic-order', 'index': 3}
```

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(order_id)             # -> '{"index":3,"type":"dynamic-order"}'
pprint(d)                    # -> {'index': 3, 'type': 'dynamic-order'}
pprint(d, sort_dicts=False)  # -> {'type': 'dynamic-order', 'index': 3}
```

(Note that `pprint.pprint()` sorts dict keys by default, which is less useful [as of Python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/4518341).)

Comment: Thanks. That solves it. I've also noticed you can import ast and use ast.literal_eval(order_id)

Comment: @DrRaspberry Definitely. I only think it's JSON cause it's using double-quotes instead of single-quotes. But on the other hand, I'm not familiar with Dash so I don't really know.